# Echoing jquery code inside PHP to make certain input receive focus

Tags: jquery, input, attributes

I have two inputs on my page, email and password, and they are part of a form that has an action to itself, or in other words, it basically just reloads on each submit until the email and password meet the requirements and then it redirects to another page. I have several if statements that tell where the issue is if there is one, and I want it to autofocus on one input or the other depending on what the issue was. I'm inside php script, so my code looks like this:

```
<?php
    if (error_1 == true) {
        echo '<script>';
            echo '$("#login_email").attr("autofocus", "autofocus");';
        echo '</script>';
    } else if (error_2 == true) {
        echo '<script>';
            echo '$("#login_password").attr("autofocus", "autofocus");';
        echo '</script>';
    }
?>
```

I've tried setting autofocus to 1 or to true, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. To sum it up, how do I make an input element recieve autofocus using jQuery?

**EDIT**: Now my code looks like this, but it still doesn't work. Just a note, the php that echos these statements is before the first `<html>` tag... is that a problem? when I inspect element on Chrome, it appears to be in the `<head>` tag... odd. The reason my php is in the head tag is because I have session functions that also happen. Here is my new code, which still does not work:

```
if (error_1 == true) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo '$(document).ready(function() {';
            echo '$("#login_email").focus();';
        echo '});';
    echo '</script>';
} else if (error_2 == true) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" >';
        echo '$(document).ready(function() {';
            echo '$("#login_password").focus();';
        echo '});';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

I've applied help from all the answers and none of the inputs get focus at all when I'm sure there are errors. What am I doing wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<script type="text/javascript">` to the first element of the `<script>`.

So it would look like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what Blaine said, but...

the reason why it is called `AJAX` is because of the return type. the `X` stands for `XML` but you could use also `JSON`. The point is, that you should in an ajax response return some structured data, and not scripts etc.

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("error" => "some error code"));
```

that data can be parsed and simply used on the client side.

```
$.post("/Login", loginData).done(function(response) {
   if (!!response.error) {
       $("#login_password").attr("autofocus", "autofocus");
   }
});
```

Disclaimer: If you dont use Ajax, ignore my post :)

Btw: If you try to `autofocus` something, be sure the document is properly loaded.

```
$(document").ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

you can also simply call `.focus()`

```
$("#login_password").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see (show me) any special reason why you are writing JavaScript/jQuery in PHP; I do not see any special variable data being output as part of jQuery/JavaScript. With that said, DOM ready is a very important event; you want to make sure to fire your code especially if it depends on the DOM as yours does when the DOM is ready:

```
$(function() { // <==== DOM ready start
    //$('#login_email').attr('autofocus','autofocus');
    //I think I know what you want to do:
    $('#login_email')[0].focus(); <====== This is what you need.
    //......
});            // <==== DOM ready end
```